# Create a test with jest of a function in javascript to check the csv.href

Tags: javascript, csv, testing, jestjs, typeerror

I need to create a test with jest to check the result of the csv.href of a function in javascript. But I am very noob to this language, also I get the following error when running the test:

"TypeError: csv.setAttribute is not a function"

// This is the function:

```
function prepareCSV(parsedJobs, newTabDocument) {
    let csv = "";
    for (const job of parsedJobs.jobs) {
        csv += `\"${job.key}\",\"${job.position}\",${job.salary},\"${job.job_link}\"\r\n`
    }
    const csvAnchor = newTabDocument.getElementById('csv');
    csvAnchor.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURI(csv);
    csvAnchor.setAttribute('download', 'report.csv')
}
```

// And this is my test:

```
const { prepareCSV } = require('./contentScript');

test('Checks that the generated CSV file is in the correct format', () => {
    const newTabDocumentMock = {
        getElementById: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
            return HTMLAnchorElement;
        })
    };
    prepareCSV(({
        'jobs': [{
            'key': 'Maplesoft, Group',
            'position': '(2), JAVA, Dervelopers',
            'salary': '',
            'job_link': 'https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=b8850651be8deeae&fccid,=9db2ebf51d,40b305&vjs=3'
        },
            {
                'key': 'Moövejób',
                'position': 'developer, software',
                'salary': '$26 an hour',
                'job_link': 'https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8a97190e957c1d14&fccid=2fcd0f7a8833b41f&vjs=5'
            },
            {
                'key': 'Español é Camões',
                'position': 'QA, tester',
                'salary': '$50 an hour',
                'job_link': 'https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8a97190e957c1d14&,f,c,c,i,d=2fcd0f7a883,3b41f&vjs=15'
            },
            {
                'key': 'Visabeira Português',
                'position': 'Full-Stack, Machine learning',
                'salary': '$45 an hour',
                'job_link': 'https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8a97190e957c1d14d=2fcd0f7a883,3b41f&vjs=7'
            }],
        'company_string': 'Maplesoft,moovejob',
        'location': 'CA',
        'job_criteria': 'java',
        'country_code': 'US'
    }), newTabDocumentMock)
})
```

I don't know how to solve the typeError, and then how to check the value of csv.href in the test

Comment: What I want to check, after fixing the "TypeError: csv.setAttribute is not a function" ... is the following:
csv.href = data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF%22Maplesoft,%20Group%22,%22(2),%20JAVA,%20Dervelopers%22,,%22https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=b8850651be8deeae&fccid,=9db2ebf51d,40b305&vjs=3%22%0D%0A%22Mo%C3%B6vej%C3%B3b%22,%22developer,%20software%22,$26%20an%20hour,%22https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8a97190e957c1d14&fccid=2fcd0f7a8833b41f&vjs=5%22%0D%0A%22Espa%C3%B1ol%20%C3%A9%20Cam%C3%B5es%22,%22QA,%20tester%22,$50%20an%20hour,%22https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?..........ETC ETC ETC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement), and you can't do `new HTMLAnchorElement()` either. You can either use `Document.createElement('a')`, or mock the element itself.

Here is your mock but modified to create an element:

```js
getElementById: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
  return Document.createElement('a');
})
```

Then you can check the `href`:

```js
expect(newTabDocumentMock.mock.results[0].value.href)// Assert something
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend, you helped me a lot